# Phpmyadmin can access from any login and password

Tags: php, linux, phpmyadmin

I have recently purchased VPS and I installed LAMP on it.
When I access Phpmyadmin through browser it asks login and password.
Even if I insert wrong password I can login successfully. I even checked it in another PC with other network, I was allowed to login.

So, How can I make a change in such a way that wrong password and login combination don't allow user to log in.

Note: I have installed fail2ban and Iptables in the server.
Checked in the phpmyadmin config file
/etc/panel/configs/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php but could not find,
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;

Comment: Change the configuration of phomyadmin. Right now it sounds like you have use passwords set to no, and something funky with usernames as well.

Comment: Normally when you login with the wrong credentials, you cannot actuall see any databases or make any changes. Is this the case with you

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, I can edit the data

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I have checked could not find. I added // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = FALSE; restart apache, still didn't work

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your MySQL installation has some security problem. Perhaps the anonymous user has been given too many privileges, or perhaps the MySQL daemon is running with the `--skip-grant-tables` option for some reason.

How did you install phpMyAdmin? Did you use some prepackaged kit, your distribution's package manager, or download the phpMyAdmin source yourself to move to your web root folder?

Start by checking the "User accounts" tab, is there an "Any" user? What are the Global privileges for that user? Does that account have any database-specific privileges? Go to one of the affected databases, the use the "Privileges" tab to see whether that user has access.

Check the main page to verify what user account you are logged in as, this is under the "Database server" section. Try logging in as a different user entirely and see if the information shown there changes at all.

Try connecting from the command line client to see if you're able to edit rows there as well.